# transfer simple View from xib to storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, storyboard, core-plot

I am using the code from this link http://www.gilthonwe.com/2012/06/09/stacked-bar-chart-coreplot-ios/ and it has a xib file with 2 views: View and Graphview .

I tried to get it to work on storyboard but its crashing. I don't know how to fix it.
I have created a storyboard file and added a view controller and changed tried changing class to viewController/UIviewController .
I have tried  both the options dont work as for Graphview I tried changing the class to graphview and removed all data from appDelegate excluding **return YES**.

I changed the main storyboard in target to the storyboard that I have created still its not working .

I want to add Navigation bar in this particular example but its not working.

Comment: What message do you get in the console when your application crashes?

Comment: I guess there is something wrong in the connections : **Storyboard ViewController has 2 connections: 2 Outlets: Graphic View - graphic view and  view - View  ,Custom class: ViewController . View has no connections and Custom Class: UIVIEW .Graphic View has 1 connection : Graphic View - ViewController  ,Custom Class : Graph View**

Comment: Is there something wrong in the connections and Custom Class ?

Comment: @geraldWilliam CorePlotBarChart* **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint' *** First throw call stack:**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error message...

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', 
reason: 'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint'
```

...suggests that you have autolayout enabled. It replaces 'springs and struts' with constraints. This is a new ios6 feature that is not present on lower versions but is automatically enabled when you make a new project. You need to disable it or you will experience these crashes on anything lower than ios6.  Go to the offending storyboard, select the file inspector (one of the right hand panels) and you will see an 'autolayout' checkbox. Untick it.

Comment: @Jacob, to avoid Q&As becoming discussions it might be best if you raised your add-on questions as new questions.

Comment: Sure Will do that now.Thanks.